# General circle identity proof

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

I very much suspect this is true but I don't have a proof of it.

Take a circle of radius $R$. Pick a point $P$ in the circle, a distance $d$ from the center of the circle. From $P$, extend $N$ ($N>1$) line segments equally-angularly-spaced connecting $A$ to the circle (orientation relative to the circle is irrelevant) (see the figure).

[image: Example geometrical orientation]

**The geometric mean of the lengths of the $N$ segments is always $\sqrt{R^2-d^2}$, irrespective of $N$ or how the segments are oriented relative to the circle.**

Does anyone know how to prove this? It seems like such a fundamental and general theorem but I haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: When $N$ is even, this boils down to the [Power of a Point Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_of_a_point). (There are $N/2$ full chords, each of which is separated into sub-chords by $P$; the product of each pair of sub-chords gives the same value, the "power" of $P$, which is $R^2-d^2$. In this case, it doesn't even matter that the segments are equally-angularly-spaced.) The fact that you get the same result for odd $N$ is interesting.

Comment: I got an expression of the length of the segments as $$\rho_k=-d\cos\left(\frac{2k\pi}N+\varphi\right)+\sqrt{R^2-d^2\sin^2\left(\frac{2k\pi}N+\varphi\right)}$$ with $0\le k<N$. From there I reach the same conclusion as Blue for $N$ even, but I'm not too sure why your conjecture would hold in the case $N$ odd...

Comment: A quick GeoGebra sketch indicates that the product of three equally-angularly-spaced segments isn't constant, so the conjecture fails for $N=3$. I suspect it only holds for even $N$, in which case it's simply  an interesting rephrasing of the Power of a Point theorem.

Comment: Yes I think it's deceptively close to a theorem, but not quite haha.
I get that the "theorem" is equivalent to:
$ 0=\sum_{k=1}^N \sinh^{-1} \left (A \sin \left ( \theta_0+\frac{2 k \pi}{N}  \right )  \right )  $
And this is true for N even, and is otherwise fairly small, in general. I think I was misled by the even cases and the smallness of the error. To be fair, it is true asymptotically for odd N haha.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the first comment, if the number of segments is even the statement is true:

> When $N$ is even, this boils down to the Power of a Point Theorem.
>   (There are $N/2$ full chords, each of which is separated into sub-chords
>   by $P$; the product of each pair of sub-chords gives the same value, the
>   "power" of $P$, which is $R^2−d^2$. In this case, it doesn't even matter
>   that the segments are equally-angularly-spaced.)

As pointed out in another comment, the statement is false when $N$ is odd, as is easily verified in a dynamic geometry package like Geogebra.  If $A$ is the set of $N$ segments, we can create another set $B$ of segments consisting of segments $b_i$ that, when paired with segments $a_i$ form full chords.  The best we can say is that, if $a$,$b$ are the geometric means of the segments in $A$ and $B$, then $\sqrt {ab} =\sqrt{R^2-d^2}.$  This is hardly earthshaking, because $A\bigcup B$ is the set of segments for $2N$, which is even.

Generally, $a$ and $b$ have only small variance as the orientation of the segments changes as in the OP animation, due to similar mixes of long and short segments in each set.